# ValueError, not enough values to unpack using Discord API

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a event so that whenever someone send a message, the bot will respond with the message with ever other character swapped case. This is what I have so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

   username = message.author.name

   if message.author == client.user:
       return

   exp = []
   for index, element in message.content:
       if index % 2 == 0:
           exp.append(element.swapcase())
       else:
           exp.append(element)

       response = "".join(exp)
   await message.channel.send(response)
```

When I run this i get a error message in Python saying:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Programmer\PycharmProjects\DiscordBotting\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Programmer\PycharmProjects\DiscordBotting\bot.py", line 33, in on_message
    for index, element in x: # message.content
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

EDIT: So I used a different method of iterating over the string shown below:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    username = message.author.name

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    exp = []

    for i in range(len(message.content)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            exp.append(message.content[i].swapcase())
        else:
            exp.append(message.content[i])

        response = "".join(exp)
    await message.channel.send(response)
```

However I still don't know why the first method didn't work.

Comment: Please put whole error message. In which line it happens? Did you try to isolate that problematic fragment for us to be able to replicate that if needed?

Comment: So it means that it is expecting to have something to unpack into `index` and `element` in `message.content`. What's there, please print it out and add into question.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content is a str, so it's rather expected.

Comment: Yes, message.content is a string so I assumed I could iterate over its characters using element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through a string, that's no a problem. Just

```py
for element in message.content:
    print(element)
```

will do a job.

But, if you want an index you must wrap that with a `enumerate`, so you need

```py
for index, element in enumerate(message.content):
    print(index, element)
```